# How to not show BaseValidator.Text when using a ValidationSummary in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, validation, customvalidator

I'm using a bunch of different asp.net validation controls on a web form.  Some of these have their Text property set to things like "* Error" or "You missed these fields".

However, a few of the CustomValidator controls have blank Text properties.  I left them blank on purpose because I'm adding the ErrorMessage dynamically depending on which case fails. (A CustomValidator may have many different conditions upon which I set args.IsValid = false)

When an error occurs, the ErrorMessage property that I set is shown both in the ValidationSummary and inside the Validator control.  I don't want that.  I want to be able to **just show the ErrorMessage in the ValidationSummary and not in the BaseValidator.Text property.**

My first try was to set the Text property to be a space " ".  That didn't work.

What I implemented (for now) is a period that is shown as the same color of the background.  It's a hack - and I don't like it.  Heck, maybe that's why I'm here!

Here's the code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="StackOverflowValidator" runat="server" 
    Text="." 
    CssClass="validatorstyle"
    Display="Dynamic" 
    OnServerValidate="validate_AllowedToDoSomething" 
    ValidationGroup="MainGroup" />

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="mainGroupValidationSummary" runat="server" 
    ValidationGroup="MainGroup" 
    DisplayMode="BulletList" 
    HeaderText="There was an error in saving.  Please check the following:" />
```

Inside validate_AllowedToDoSomething I call:

```
StackOverflowValidator.ErrorMessage = "Custom Error Message #1";
args.IsValid = false;
return;
```

What I get is "Custom Error Message #1" **twice** on the web form.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set `display="none"` instead of `"dynamic"` on the BaseValidator, and that should solve it.

Comment: It worked!

I had also tried setting it to invisible, but that causes the validation to not be run at all.  I guess that the None option on the Display attribute was made just for this cause.

Thanks again.